# Dart future and rethrow

Tags: dart, future

Is there any `rethrow` (not `throw`) equivalent for futures in dart?

```dart
myFunc()
.then(processValue)
.catchError(handleError);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If the `handleError` of a [`catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-async/Future/catchError.html) throws the same error object again (because it acts the same way as [`then`'s `onError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-async/Future/then.html#:%7E:text=rethrow)), it is considered a "rethrow" and it will also retain the original stack trace.

If you just want to catch *some* types of errors, and rethrow the rest, you can use the test parameter of [`catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-async/Future/catchError.html):

```dart
myFunc()
  .then(processValue)
  .catchError(handleError, test: (e) => e is MyException);
```

This only catches `MyException` exceptions and lets any other error pass through, with no need for you to rethrow them. The `test` can do any testing, not just type checks.

Also, if you use `async` functions, you can just use `rethrow`:

```dart
...) async {
  try {
    var processValue = await myFunc();
    ....
  } catch (e) {
    if (something(e)) {
      whatnot();
    } else {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```